# No water flow after closing and reopening shutoff valve

Tags: plumbing, water, shutoff

My faucet was in need of attention so went below the sink, shut off the valves, unscrewed the supply lines, cleaned the faucet put everything back and now the water won't turn back on at the valves. It's not the faucet.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that the valve is opening?  Sometimes when older gate valves are not used for a long time, they get stuck open/closed when they are finally used.  If the valve is stuck, you can either attempt to repair it, or you can replace it.

Answer (score 5):

I have found on old valves the valve stem separates from the gate. they close fine but then it feels like it is opening but is broke.
You will probably need to turn the water to the house off , bleed the pressure off and remove the valve and install a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Completely removed the faucet to "clean" it? Do you mean re-built it after cleaning all of the scale off of it from an ongoing leak? Hook the hoses up to the valve connections, insert & hold them down into the drain pipe to check valve operation & water flow. If the valves are still good, you'll need to re-check your faucet work.